# Combine SQL rows into one column based off two other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    bs.ITEMNAME AS Item,
    bom.ITEM AS PartNumber,
    STUFF(SELECT ed.NOTE AS [text()] 
     WHERE bom.ITEM = ed.itemid 
     FOR XML PATH ('')) AS Description
FROM 
    vwAXBOM bom
LEFT JOIN 
    S2BOMSTR bs ON bom.POSITION = bs.ITEMNUM
LEFT JOIN 
    vwExtendedDescriptionMFG ed ON bom.ITEM = ed.itemid
WHERE 
    bom.BOMITEM = @partNum 
    AND bom.POSITION LIKE 'S%'  
    AND bom.POSITION != 'S76'
```

It returns a table like:

```
| Item | PartNumber | Description
+------+------------+--------------
| Film |  1234      | Some thing
| Film |  1234      | Other thing
| Flap |  5678      | Another thing
| Flap |  5678      | Final Thing
```

But I am looking to have something like this:

```
| Item | PartNumber | Description
+------+------------+---------------------------
| Film |   1234     | Some thing, Other thing
| Flap |   5678     | Another thing, Final thing
```

How do I change my SQL statement to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I am using sql server 2016 so I cannot, it comes back as an invalid function

Comment: I've already tried to look for replacements for STRING_AGG and thats where I found FOR XML, but I can't get the statement right. And thats why I'm asking for help and how to improve my statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being to create a temp table for the main query. Then pulling the appropriate data out of the temp table utilizing the FOR XML PATH () function.

```
SELECT
     bs.ITEMNAME AS Item
    ,bom.ITEM AS PartNumber
INTO #tempBomList
FROM vwAXBOM bom
    LEFT JOIN S2BOMSTR bs 
        ON bom.POSITION = bs.ITEMNUM
    LEFT JOIN vwExtendedDescriptionMFG ed
        ON bom.ITEM = ed.itemid
    WHERE bom.BOMITEM = @partNum AND bom.POSITION LIKE 'S%'  AND bom.POSITION <> 'S76' 
GROUP BY bs.ITEMNAME
        ,bom.ITEM
        
SELECT tb.Item
        ,tb.PartNumber
        ,(SELECT NOTE +  ', '
                FROM vwExtendedDescriptionMFG 
                WHERE ITEMID = tb.PartNumber
                FOR XML PATH('')) AS Description
FROM #tempBomList tb
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example of this is:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 'a' as A
    union all
    select 'b'
    union all
    select 'c')
select stuff((select ', '+A from cte for xml path('')),1,2,'')
```

output: `a,b,c`

Comment: This command works and outputs what you said, I'm currently trying to work with it in incorporating it into my use case. As I'm trying to also account for the other two columns as well

Answer (score 0):

To use XML like this you also need the STUFF function to concatenate the strings for you. Something like this (but may need tweaking):

```
SELECT
    bs.ITEMNAME AS Item,
    bom.ITEM AS PartNumber,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + ed.NOTE AS [text()] 
     WHERE bom.ITEM = ed.itemid 
     FOR XML PATH ('') ),1,1,'') AS [Description]
FROM 
    vwAXBOM bom
LEFT JOIN 
    S2BOMSTR bs ON bom.POSITION = bs.ITEMNUM
LEFT JOIN 
    vwExtendedDescriptionMFG ed ON bom.ITEM = ed.itemid
WHERE 
    bom.BOMITEM = @partNum 
    AND bom.POSITION LIKE 'S%'  
    AND bom.POSITION <> 'S76'
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding just the STUFF at the beginning still renders the same output for me.